# Angular getting Json Values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Hello I´m having trouble invoking the values of a Json Array using Angular JS.

Heres the JSON array (updated):

```
    "incidentes":
    [
      {
      "id": 1,
      "estado": "Activo",
      "aperturafecha": "08/08/2014",
      "aperturahora": "14:00:00",
      "clasificacion": "Actualización",
      "diagnostico": "Actualizacion de software",
      "resolucion": "Actualizaciones realizadas",
      "insumos": "Ninguno",
      "cierrefecha": "08/08/2014",
      "cierrehora": "14:05:00",
      "prioridad": "Media",
      "indisponibilidad": "00:05:00",
      "codename": "A1",
      "tipoincidente": "S",
      "hardwares": [],
      "sistemas": [{
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 19
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 19,
          "nombre": "Prestadores",
          "descripcion": "Sistema de carga de prestadores",
          "criticidad": "ALTA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 19,
              "sistemaid": 19
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 20
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 20,
          "nombre": "Wiki",
          "descripcion": "Wiki para difusión de conocimientos relavantes al area de Informatica",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 19,
              "sistemaid": 20
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 21
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 21,
          "nombre": "Ocs",
          "descripcion": "Servico de iventariado de computadoras.",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 19,
              "sistemaid": 21
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 22
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 22,
          "nombre": "Incidentes",
          "descripcion": "Aplicacion de carga y consulta de Incidentes",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 19,
              "sistemaid": 22
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 1
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 1,
          "nombre": "Relay Correo y Página",
          "descripcion": "Relay Correo electrónico y página web",
          "criticidad": "ALTA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 1,
              "sistemaid": 1
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 2
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre": "Correo",
          "descripcion": "Correo electrónico",
          "criticidad": "ALTA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 2,
              "sistemaid": 2
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 3
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 3,
          "nombre": "Consultas Públicas",
          "descripcion": "Consulta sobre CUD",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 16,
              "sistemaid": 3
            }
          }, {
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 1,
              "sistemaid": 3
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 4
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 4,
          "nombre": "Aplicaciones Internas",
          "descripcion": "Servicio de aplicaciones internas",
          "criticidad": "ALTA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 4,
              "sistemaid": 4
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 5
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 5,
          "nombre": "Nube",
          "descripcion": "Servicio de storage on the cloud",
          "criticidad": "BAJA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 5,
              "sistemaid": 5
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 6
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 6,
          "nombre": "Backup",
          "descripcion": "Backup",
          "criticidad": "CRITICA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 6,
              "sistemaid": 6
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 7
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 7,
          "nombre": "Pentaho",
          "descripcion": "Sistema de información estadístico",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 7,
              "sistemaid": 7
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 8
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 8,
          "nombre": "Router",
          "descripcion": "Router + DHCP + DNS + Proxy + VPN Server",
          "criticidad": "CRITICA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 8,
              "sistemaid": 8
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 9
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 9,
          "nombre": "Base de Datos",
          "descripcion": "Base de Datos",
          "criticidad": "CRITICA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 9,
              "sistemaid": 9
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 10
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 10,
          "nombre": "Discapacidad",
          "descripcion": "Aplicación de carga y consulta de CUD",
          "criticidad": "ALTA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 10,
              "sistemaid": 10
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 11
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 11,
          "nombre": "Monitor",
          "descripcion": "Monitor",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 11,
              "sistemaid": 11
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 12
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 12,
          "nombre": "Testing general",
          "descripcion": "Testing de apps",
          "criticidad": "BAJA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 11,
              "sistemaid": 12
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 13
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 13,
          "nombre": "Testing Deportes",
          "descripcion": "Testing de app Deportes (Beta)",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 11,
              "sistemaid": 13
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 14
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 14,
          "nombre": "Control de Versiones",
          "descripcion": "Control de versiones y backup de codigo fuente",
          "criticidad": "CRITICA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 12,
              "sistemaid": 14
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 15
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 15,
          "nombre": "Win Server 2012",
          "descripcion": "Controlador de Dominio, servicio de deployment de SO, servidor de archvos",
          "criticidad": "ALTA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 15,
              "sistemaid": 15
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 16
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 16,
          "nombre": "Intranet",
          "descripcion": "Intranet y sistema de ticket",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 18,
              "sistemaid": 16
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 17
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 17,
          "nombre": "Testing VM",
          "descripcion": "Testing general",
          "criticidad": "BAJA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 18,
              "sistemaid": 17
            }
          }]
        }
      }, {
        "id": {
          "incidenteid": 1,
          "sistemaid": 18
        },
        "sistema": {
          "id": 18,
          "nombre": "Deportes",
          "descripcion": "Sistema de carga de usuarios de pileta",
          "criticidad": "MEDIA",
          "estado": "Activo",
          "activo": true,
          "softwares": [{
            "id": {
              "softwareid": 18,
              "sistemaid": 18
            }
          }]
        }
      }],
      "softwares": [],
      "tecnico": {
        "id": 4,
        "nombre": "Lucas Ignacio Sarafian",
        "legajo": "400450",
        "email": "lsarafian@snr.gob.ar",
        "interno": "5224"
      }
    }]
```

Heres the HTML page I'm using to show the data. (updated)

```
   <body ng-controller="IncidenteController">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tecnicos.html">Tecnicos</a></li>
        <li><a href="/sistemas.html">Sistemas</a></li>
        <li><a href="/incidentes.html">Incidentes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login.html">login</a></li>
        <li ng-show="authenticated"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<form role="form">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-info">
                    <th class="col-md-1" data-align="center">Fecha Apertura</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1" data-align="center">Hora Apertura</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2" data-align="center">Clasificacion</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2" data-align="center">Diagnostico</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2" data-align="center">Resolucion</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1" data-align="center">Insumos</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1" data-align="center">Fecha de Cierre</th>
                    <th class="col-md-1" data-align="center">Hora de Cierre</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2" data-align="center">Prioridad</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2" data-align="center">Indisponibilidad</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2" data-align="center">Sistemas Afectados</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="incidente in incidentes">
                <tr >
                    <td class="col-md-1" data-align="center">{{incidente.aperturafecha}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-1" data-align="center">{{incidente.aperturahora}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2" data-align="center">{{incidente.clasificacion}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2" data-align="center">{{incidente.diagnostico}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2" data-align="center">{{incidente.resolucion}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-1" data-align="center">{{incidente.insumos}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-1" data-align="center">{{incidente.cierrefecha}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-1" data-align="center">{{incidente.cierrehora}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2" data-align="center">{{incidente.prioridad}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2" data-align="center">{{incidente.indisponibilidad}}</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2" data-align="center">{{incidente['sistemas'][0].sistema.nombre}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

According to that it should reflect the values but it doesnt I tried every single convination i can think of....

Heres the angular file:

```
  .controller('IncidenteController', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

var urlbase = "http://localhost:8080/get/";

var onError = function(reason) {
    $scope.error = "No se pudo encontrar";
};

var onIncidenteComplete = function(response) {
    $scope.incidentes = response.data;
    $scope.sistema = incidente.sistema; <--- this is useless
};

$http.get(urlbase + "incidente/").then(onIncidenteComplete, onError);

$scope.obtenerSistemas = function(incidente) {
    $scope.sistema = incidente.sistema;
};
```

[error console log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=n4TpK4kH) [log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQCnU.jpg)

UDPDATE: " I can now get the values out of the JSON array but cant seem to figure out the way to use NG-repeat to show em.

**Edit: I added a example of the solution in my code for anyone who might need it plus the function to get a object inside the object in the array.

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-info">
                <th data-align="center">Nombre del Sistema Afectado</th>
                <th data-align="center">Funcion</th>
                <th data-align="center">Estado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="sistema in incidente.sistemas" class="">
                <td data-align="center">{{sistema.sistema.nombre}}</td>
                <td data-align="center">{{sistema.sistema.descripcion}}</td>
                <td data-align="center">{{sistema.sistema.estado}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have you inspected `response.data` to make sure it is what you think it is? What is being displayed? Why is your `ng-repeat` on the `<table>`? It's usually on the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data comes as an array, this should be enough:

```
var onIncidenteComplete = function(response) {

  $scope.incidentes = response.data[0].incidentes;
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/IBvlqSaSd79p67ctQrIl?p=preview

edit: http://plnkr.co/edit/MvtAaftloGtgtfaUA6Eg?p=preview
plnkr demo for the nested consult.

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to try angular.fromJson(data)?

I have this:

```
var parsedDashboard = angular.fromJson(data);

console.log(parsedDashboard);
```

Data is from an HTML response of json data.

The above works in Angular 1.4.6

In your case then it should be:

```
$scope.incidentes = angular.fromJson(your json data here)
```

Also try putting your ng-repeat on the tr instead of table its self:

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="customers" class="table   table-striped" id='customers'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="id">ID</th>
            <th st-sort="name">Name</th>
            <th st-sort="total">Total Ordered in {{searchObject.Duration}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr st-select-row="row" ng-repeat="x in displayedCollection" ng-click="setSelected(this)" class="{{selected}}">
            <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.name }} </td>
            <td>{{ x.total | currency : '$' : 2 }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tboday>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="displayedPages"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn´t make any difference, and I usually put the ng-repeat in the TR i switched it try some things coz nothing seems to work, I´m not sure if I´m invoking it wrong or if I should fix my angular.controller.

Comment: If you do "Console.log($scope.incidentes)" do you see your json values in there? I usually do plain http requests with get and post data. Also what about if you console.log(response) and see what all it is pulling in from there?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VIIIWgj.jpg

Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 1 more… ] incidente.js:63:6

Comment: Shouldnt the json data be taken out of the array? If you set $scope.incidentes = $scope.incidented[0] then you would just have all the json data. That might be whats causing it.

Comment: According to angular documentation: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). I would also make sure that each object has a proper (key,value) pair.

Comment: UDPDATE: " I can now get the values out of the JSON array but cant seem to figure out the way to use NG-repeat to show em.

Comment: try taking the "data" off of ng-repeat? I have never used a validator of my own which i assume $scope.obtenerSistemas is. However, from the error log it sounds to me that the error is occurring for some reason with the your validation function.